# Get returned JSON from AsyncTask

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, return

So I have this loader class which extends AsyncTask. Then I do `new loader().execute();` but I want to use the **JSONArray response** which my loader class **returns** how do I do that? Because I need it in several different places? Or should I just move my code to onPostExecute and do everything from there?

```
public class loader extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, JSONArray> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    protected void onPreExecute() {

        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ChallengeList.this, "", "Laddar...");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) {


    JSONArray response = null;
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(listURL);

    try {

        HttpResponse resp = client.execute(httppost);
        StatusLine statusLine = resp.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        Log.i("Statuscode", "statusCode"+statusCode);
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            final JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

            json.put("userID", prefs.id());

            response = SendHttp.parseHttp(listURL, json);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } 

        return response;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `onPostExecute` has as parameter the `JSONArray` you returned from the `doInBackground` method.

`onPostExecute` runs on your main (caller) activity's thread, so besides dismissing the dialog in that method, you can process the `result` array further, pass it safely to other methods, etc:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result)
{
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    final Message msg = new Message();
    msg.obj = result;
    if (youWantToUseHandler)
        handler.dispatchMessage(msg);
    else
        writeJSONArray(result);
}
```

**the `handler`:**

```
final Handler handler = new Handler()
{
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
    {
        final JSONArray result = (JSONArray)msg.obj;
        writeJSONArray(result);
    };
};
```

Some other method:

```
private void writeJSONArray(final JSONArray result)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++)
    {
        try
        {
            Log.d("SAMPLE", result.get(i).toString());
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            Log.e("SAMPLE", "error getting result " + i, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Since `onPostExecute` "Runs on the UI thread after doInBackground. The specified result is the value returned by doInBackground or null if the task was cancelled or an exception occured." ~API Docs
You can call any method you've declared in your class, and pass this array as a parameter to it.

Comment: But isn't there a way to use it outside onPostExecute? Like getting the JSONArray after I've done new loader().execute(); and then just use it in my main code?

Comment: you can pass it to a handler for example, and use it from there. declare a Handler in your main application, and call it from onPostExecute.

Answer (score 0):

After downloading the content web you can use the code below in onPostExecute method:

protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

```
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);

            String weatherInfo = jsonObject.getString("weather");

            Log.i("Weather content", weatherInfo);

            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(weatherInfo);

            for (int i=0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                Log.i("main",jsonPart.getString("main"));
                Log.i("description",jsonPart.getString("description"));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```