# Grab return value of asynctask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, return

is it possible to grab the return value of the doInBackground()-method?

```
JSONArray response = new SupportFunctions.executeURLWithResponse().execute(url);
```

It tells me:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Type mismatch: cannot convert from AsyncTask<String,Void,JSONArray> to JSONArray          ContactFunctions.java /BuddyCheck/src/com/pthuermer/buddycheck    line 138    Java Problem
```

Something like this?

Comment: did you try reading the documentation ?

Comment: If the task is in a separate file you can use an `interface`. [Here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517400/inner-class-can-access-but-not-update-values-asynctask/18517648#18517648) otherwise you can update the value or call a function to set the value in `onPostExecute()`

Comment: codeMagic is right, you need to `@Override` `void  onPostExecute(Result result)`

Comment: and then? where is the result? I cant return something out of onPostExecute, right?

Comment: See my linked answer about using an interface

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to grab the return value of the doInBackground()-method?

Not in the manner that you are trying.

There is a `get()` method you can call to block the current thread and wait for the asynchronous work to complete. That usually is not what you want -- you specifically *want* the work to be done asynchronously (otherwise, why have an `AsyncTask`?).

Move you code that needs the `JSONArray` response either into `onPostExecute()` itself or into some other method that will be executed by `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: I'm using asynctask because its the only way to grab a JSON response from an URL, right?

Comment: @user3432220 No. You need (should) to do it on a background thread but that doesn't mean you have to use an `AsyncTask`, though it is often used for this type of thing. You should read about threading [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

Comment: @user3432220: You need to use a background thread to "grab a JSON response from an URL". An `AsyncTask` is a wrapper around a background thread. But the reason why you need a background thread is so that you do not tie up the main application thread waiting for network I/O. Process the results of the `AsyncTask` background work in `onPostExecute()` -- that's why it is there.

Comment: would it be easier to grab the jsonarray response from a background thread?

Comment: @user3432220 you are using a background thread. That's what `doInBackground()` is. The `AsyncTask` class just also has methods to update the Ui.

Comment: okay, so thats confusing. would the thread possible return the array?

Answer (score 0):

You can make response a class or global variable then set the variable when the async task finishes. Most of what you should be doing should be in your override of onPostExecute.

[Get returned JSON from AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575072/get-returned-json-from-asynctask?rq=1)